# Proving an inequality regarding increasing or decreasing sequences

Tags: calculus, inequality, rearrangement-inequality

> Suppose $a_1 \geq a_2 $ and $b_1 \geq b_2$. Prove that
>
> $$ (a_1+a_2)(b_1+b_2) \leq 2 (a_1b_1 + a_2 b_2) $$
>
> Generalize

### sol attempt:

We can write $a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + a_2 b_1 + a_1 b_2 \leq 2a_1 b_1 + 2 a_2 b_2 $

and so

$$ a_2 b_1 + a_1 b_2 \leq a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 \iff  0 \leq (a_1-a_2) b_1 + (b_1 - b_2) a_1$$

Now, certainly $a_2 - a_1 \geq 0$ and $b_1 - b_2 \geq 0$ by hypothesis. So, as long as $b_1 \geq 0$ and $a_1 \geq 0$ we are done. If by contradiction $b_1 < 0$ then $b_1 < b_1 - b_2 $ and so $b_2 < 0$ but I dont see how to get a contradiction from here...

I guess we have to consider cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ a_2 b_1 + a_1 b_2 \leq a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 \iff  0 \leq (a_1-a_2) b_1 + (b_1 - b_2) a_1$$ is wrong.

What you get is $$ a_2 b_1 + a_1 b_2 \leq a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2$$ $$ \iff  0 \leq (a_1-a_2) b_1 + (a_2 - a_1) b_2 \iff  0 \leq (a_1-a_2) (b_1-b_2)$$  which is true.

Comment: I see my arithmetic mistake. However, your last $\iff$ I am afraid is not always true

Comment: Write the second term as $-(a_1-a_2)b_2$. Now pull out the common factor $a_1-a_2$. That gives the last equiavalence. Finally $a_1-a_2 \geq 0$ and $b_1 -b_2 \geq 0$. Hence their product is $\geq 0$. @James

Answer (score 1):

It's a private case of the Chebyshov's inequality:

> Let $a_1\geq a_2\geq ...\geq a_n$ and $b_1\geq b_2\geq...\geq b_n$. Prove that:
>   $$n(a_1b_1+a_2b_2+...+a_nb_n)\geq(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)(b_1+b_2+...+b_n).$$

For $n=2$ we obtain your inequality.

A proof of the Chebyshov's inequality we get immediately by Rearrangement, which we can prove by induction.

Comment: Thanks! Since you mention rearrangament, I do have a question. Suppose we are trying to prove an inequality of the form $f(a_1+...+a_n) \leq g(a_1,...,a_n)$, say for example $ ( \frac{1}{n} \sum a_i )^p \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum a_k^p $ where $a_i \geq 0$, Can we assume that the $a_i$ are ordered ?? for instance can we assume $a_1 \geq a_2 \geq ... \geq a_n$? Im failing to see this

Comment: @James Yes, you can do it because your last inequality is symmetric.

Comment: Im sorry to ask this stupid question but what do you exactly mean when you say the inequality is symetric

Comment: @James It says that the inequality is not changed after any permutations of $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n).$

Comment: THANKS!! I got it now

Comment: @James You are welcome!